# Using UNION ALL with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, database, union

I have 3 tables. I have unified two of them using `UNION ALL`, but I cannot unify the third because there is only one field in common `"receipt"`.

I want to get a output like:

`costumerid/ amount  / receipt / saledate /cost`

**My code right now is:**

```
SELECT t1.costumerid, t1.amount, t1.receipt, t1.saledate
FROM t1
WHERE t1.amount>'100' AND t1.saledate<Date()-180 
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.costumerid, t2.amount, t2.receipt, t2.saledate
FROM t2
WHERE t2.amount>'100' AND t2.saledate<Date()-180
```

Any help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create alias for your outputs columns.

```
SELECT t1.costumerid, t1.amount, t1.receipt, t1.saledate FROM t1 WHERE t1.amount>'100' AND t1.saledate<Date()-180 UNION ALL SELECT t2.costumerid, t2.amount, t2.receipt, t2.saledate FROM t2 WHERE t2.amount>'100' AND t2.saledate<Date()-180 UNION ALL select null as 'costumerid',null as 'amount' t3.receipt , null as 'saledate' from t3
```

I don't know in which table you want to find the column cost but you just have to follow the logical.

Comment: "cost" column is on t3.